# What is the song played in the radio station just before the semi-finals?

Tags: soundtrack, pitch-perfect

This song was a remix composed by Beca in the movie.

**What is the song played in the radio station just before the semi-finals?**

Comment: Can you be more specific about the scene? Is it when she's working in the Radio station? Or the song that the station manager is playing when he offers her a show? If you can give a minute count of the scene, that would help.

Comment: I am talking about the song in the background at 1:06:31.

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Same time code.

Comment: sorry, this is what i was searching for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about the scene that starts around 1:06:30 (on my copy, anyway) when she's running into the campus radio station and the station manager offers her a slot in the lineup, it looks like it's a remix of *[Bulletproof](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kk8eJh4i8Lo)* by [LaRoux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Roux) and *[Release Me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0G7eDpMGe1k)* by [Agnes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agnes_Carlsson):